# Javascript array deletion for garbage collection

Tags: javascript, performance, garbage-collection

I have a javascript array of objects that are each created with 'new'. In the event of an error I would like to clear the whole array so that it would be GC'ed by the JS engine. To this end is it sufficient to just set the array variable to 'null' or do I need to splice all the elements from the array and set them to null before setting the array variable to 'null'?

The reason I am asking is that in Firefox I displayed (console.log) the array before assigning it to null and the displayed object (which is usually updated in the display I assume even later) still shows the elements of the array when I inspect it later, hence my doubt if the elements are actually being free'd or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To clear an array you can just set the length to zero:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(arr);
arr.length=0;
console.log(arr);
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[]
```

Edit:
Just found this on the topic: http://davidwalsh.name/empty-array

Looking at the comments it seems that just setting the variable to a new array is the simplest method:

```
arr = [];
```

According to the test results the memory is GC'd quicker than setting the length to 0. I would imagine this is to do with the allocations triggering the GC.

There is an interesting performance test on various methods here: http://jsperf.com/array-destroy

Comment: Would this ensure the free'ing of the objects within it as well?

Comment: @source.rar - I think so, as long as you aren't holding a reference to them elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Considering both Chrome and Firefox, setting the arr to null (arr = null) seems to be the best bet for acceptable performance.

Comment: another performance test: https://jsperf.com/truncating-arrays-correctly showing no big difference between [] and length = 0